# AEM 6.1 || How can I add some renditions parameter to the image name in sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

I want to add some renditions parameter to the image name in sightly component html. For example, if my image name is sample.png , then I want to make it sample.1024.png. Is there any way we can do that in sightly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Class which extend WCMUse and do image path processing in this class. Then use this class in your component;s HTML. Also, have a look at [Sightly image component](http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/foundation/components/image)